# Background color changes when projecting a raster with ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, coordinate-system, arctoolbox, arcgis-10.4

I'm using the [Project Raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project-raster.htm) tool via `arcpy`:

```
 arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(
     in_raster = clipped_raster,
     out_raster = projected_clipped_raster,
     out_coor_system = COORDINATE_SYSTEM_WGS_1984_WEB_MERCATOR,
     resampling_type = "CUBIC",
     geographic_transform = TRANSFORM_US_IFR_TO_WGS_1984_WEB_MERCATOR,
     in_coor_system = COORDINATE_SYSTEM_US_IFR)
```

Before the image has a white background:

[image]

But after the projection, its grey:

[image]

Any idea why this would be happening?

**---- EDIT ----**

Per the suggestion by @Fetzer, I check the `Stretch` setting.  I see it has `Percent Clip`:

[image]

However, when I set it to `None` per his suggestion, the grey actually gets darker:

[image]

Comment: What about turning off Gamma Stretch? or adjusting the settings for min/max to 0.5 or something...

Comment: @Fezter, turning off Gamma Stretch lightens the grey a little bit, adjusting min/max, also lightens the grey a tiny bit.  Combining the 2 makes no additional difference...  I did notice that, on the display tab, Contrast was set to 10% (original image was 0, so no clue why that got set to 10).  When I changed it to 0, it got darker...  So i changed it to 50, and the grey practically disappears.  Any idea why that would be?  Also, at the risk of sounding ignorant (which i am), what led you to think transparency/stretch in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things might be happening here.

1. You have a transparency on the layer (unlikely).
2. You have a stretch type defined in the symbology for the raster.

   This might be standard deviation:
   [image]

Set it to **None** and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yup, it does have a stretch.  And it is set to `Percent Clip`.  Setting it to `None` actually made the grey darker...  (see edit above)